# ASP.NET Core Identity session expires sooner than it is configured to happen

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

So in my application I've configured the identity as:

```
services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.Cookie.Name = "application_ms_state";
                cfg.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(1);
                cfg.SlidingExpiration = true;
            });
```

but the expiration happens in almost 20 minutes.could anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Maybe this will help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37086645/how-to-set-asp-net-identity-cookies-expires-time

Comment: I already use signInManager.SignInAsync directly with `IsPersistent = true` but still no luck!

Comment: What do you have for ExpireTimeSpan set up in Startup.cs? (Mentioned in linked post)

Comment: i am using identity 2.0.0 and it is configured the other way as i posted in question.in v 2.0.0 it's `cfg.Cookie.Expiration`

Comment: What about directly adding IsPersistent = true to the services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(cfg => method you mentioned above?

Comment: there is no such an option in CookieAuhenticationOption and its not rational to be one either.

Comment: cfg.Cookie.ExpireTimeSpan Is not valid?

Comment: `ExpireTimeSpan`  is renamed to `Expiration` in version 2.0.0.

Comment: The browser isn't being closed or the server restarted is it?

Comment: @Tratcher what do you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the doc comments. https://github.com/aspnet/Security/blob/a53bf093a7d86b35e019c80515c92d7626982325/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies/CookieAuthenticationOptions.cs#L147
ExpiresTimeSpan and Expiration control different things. ExpiresTimeSpan is the one used for sliding expiration.

Comment: i applied `ExpiresTimeSpan` and waiting for the result.i'll mark u as answer after 40 mins or so if i didn't log out after that time span :D.

Comment: i mark you as answer because it's more likely to be the common problem but posting my own answer for those who just in case face similar problem.thanks in advance for sticking to problem.

Answer (score 4):

After days of searching thanks to guys behind [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38401272/asp-net-core-identity-3-cookie-timeout/38463829#38463829) i figured out that the problem is ,identity checks every 30 minutes (by default, its configurable) to see if issued authentication ticked is valid, consequently it checks to see if the class which is implementing `UserStore<>` is implementing `IUserSecurityStampStore` (`UserManager.SupportsUserSecurityStamp`) for that matter. As my MembershipService class which is implementing `IUserStroe` does not implement `IUserSecurityStampStore<>` thus after 30 min interval i end up with invalid security stamp and a null principal which == `SignOut`.

check this [github issue](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/issues/1425#issuecomment-329372381) to get a reference for mentioned code snippets.